# How to create 3 layer Combo Box (Active X Control) on a sheet - Excel VBA

Tags: excel, vba

I am trying to create a 3 layer combo box drop down on one of my sheets (not in a form).

I achieved this using data validation and named ranges but the drop down arrow only appears when you click on the box which is annoying and I want this tool to be as intuitive as possible for the users.

I have found examples of 2 layer combo boxes using switch cases which I can kind of follow but the next layer is hurting my head.

```
Layer 1 - Route (30 Values)
Layer 2 - Conveyor Number (5-10 Values per Route)
Layer 3 - Record Reference (4-20 Values per Conveyor Number)
```

I want to read the values from the combo boxes and pass to various command buttons on the sheet.

If there is an easy way of doing this rather than writing out many switch cases that would be great

I have included an image of Route 1 to give context and an image of my dashboard.

[image]

[image]

Comment: Conveyor Number or Measuring Point do not appear on your image supplied.

Comment: **1.** Which Excel Version do you have? **2.** Instead of `ActiveX Combobox`, I would recommend using `Form Combobox`. You can get Dependent lists in `Form Combobox` as well.

Comment: Forgot to mention an important detail... `You can get Dependent lists in Form Combobox as well without using VBA`

Comment: Sorry Route, Conveyor Number and Measuring Points data is on the other sheets

Comment: 1. Im using Microsoft Office Professional Plus 2019


2. Ok, I thought Active X was better as I can right the code behind the combo box whereas form control version it doesn't seem like you can? Im using the combo box on a sheet not actually on a pop up form. How do I make dependent lists on a form control version of a combo box, right-click>format control> Control Tab doesnt seem to have any options to create a dependent list

Comment: It would be hard to help you make the combo boxes dynamic, we don't know where the other information is for the second and third lists